# If $f$ is zero except in a closed set $A$ of zero measure, then its integral it's zero?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $B\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a rectangle. Let $f:B\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. If $f$ is zero, except in a closed set $A$ of zero measure, then $f$ is Riemann integrable and $\int_Bf=0$?
Here is my attempt so far:

First, note that $A=\{x\in B | f(x)\neq 0\}$.
Let $x\not\in A$. Then, $x\in A^c\cap B$.

Since $A$ is closed, $A^c$ is open and so it's $A^c\cap B$.

With this, we have that $\forall\ \varepsilon >0 \ \exists\ \delta>0$ s.t.

$V_\delta (x)\subset (A^c\cap B)$ and, if $y\in V_\delta (x)$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|=|0-0|=0<\varepsilon$. So $f$ is continous at $x$ if $x\not\in A$.

This implies that, if $D_f:=\{x\in B | f \text{ is not continous at }x\}$, then $D_f\subset A$.

With that, since $A$ has zero measure,  $D_f$ must have zero measure and $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Now, i have proved before that:

If $C\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded set, $g:C\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Riemann integrable function, and the set $E:=\{x\in C | g(x)\neq 0\}$ is zero measure, then $\int_Cf=0$.

Thus, $\int_B f=0$.

I have some questions for my proof attempt:

- I don't remember exactly if $A^c\cap B$ is open.
- Am I correct in saying that $D_f\subset A$? A classmate told me is easy to proof after that $D_f=A$ but he's argument didn't convince me.
- Is even correct to say that $A=\{x\in B| f(x)\neq 0\}$?
- The theorem I mentioned at the end is defined for any bounded set, so it's correct to use it here since B is a rectangle and rectangles are bounded, right? In my class we consider rectangles as $R=[a_1,b_1]\times\cdots\times [a_n, b_n]\ \subset\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: You can't say that $A$ is open because you don't know if $f$ is continuous. But $A$ is indeed the set you specified.

Comment: Sorry, it's on the opposite side, A is closed by hypothesis. I made the correction. @Izralbu

Comment: Arguably, we actually have $A \supseteq \{x \in B : f(x) \neq 0\}$ rather than equality, but the argument from that point on is identical.

Comment: $A^c \cap B$ is open in $B$. The Riemann integrability proof is alright. The theorem you mention isn't clear.

Comment: @BrianMoehring How so?

Comment: @Izralbu I writed the theorem again as I saw it in class, hope is clear enough.

Comment: @lzralbu "$f$ is zero except on $A$" isn't formal enough to be unambiguous.  I tend to interpret it as "If $f(x) \neq 0,$ then $x \in A$" from which we have the set inclusion rather than equality.  Perhaps the better argument, however, is that the inclusion is the weaker property and the proof stays the same, so we end up with a stronger theorem with no additional work.

Comment: @BrianMoehring so, how can I add this required "additional work"?

Comment: @ArmandoRosas I would still say it's "no additional work".  The full extent of the change would be "First note that $A \color{red}{\supseteq} \{x \in B : f(x) \neq 0\}$" and then at the end of the next line "$A^c \cap B \color{red}{\subseteq \{x \in B : f(x) = 0\}}$" purely for emphasis.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Ok, I'll make the change on my homework, thanks for the advice.